# Retain band names in mosaic dataset Extract Bands

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mosaic, mosaic-dataset, sentinel-2

I have a collection of multi-band Sentinel-2 rasters. From these, I apply the *Extract Band* Raster Function. On the resulting mosaic dataset, I need to retain the initial band names. For example, if I extract B4 (red) and B8 (ir) bands, in the resulting mosaic dataset, I will have B1 and B2 as names, but they can be easily misinterpreted as B1 (coastal aerosol) and B2 (blue) bands.

Is there a way in ArcMap or Python to retain the original band names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python solution might be tricky but [this ESRI blog post](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/07/24/displaying-imagery-with-appropriate-band-name-labels/) shows doing this in ArcGIS Desktop. Basically you need to access to the new mosaic's properties and, from `General` tab, change Product Definition to `Custom` from where you can specify band names and preferably wavelengths.